# Check if an exe is already running

Tags: windows-runtime, exe, status

Could someone show how it is possible to check whether another instance of the program (e.g. test.exe) is running and if so return the istance of such program beacuse I need to use a method of a class in that current status?

I would like that when I lanch the exe, first it check if it is already executing. If so, I want the status and working on the same state. Otherwise it can open a new one...

Comment: You could write a .bat script around the program, that saves the status to the file.
I'm not sure, what do you mean under "return the instance"?

Comment: The question is tagged `windows-runtime`, but in WinRT, there is only one copy of a program running. If the user tries to run the program again, the system just reactivates the existing copy. Perhaps you intended to tag as `winapi` instead?